# Why were Python packages installed in the user folder?

Tags: python, libraries

I installed Python 3.10.1 on Windows 10 using 'for all users' option to C:\Program Files\python310 folder. Then Python libraries are expected to be installed in the C:\Program files\python310\lib\site-packages folder. But they actually are located in C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\python310\site-packages except for pip and setuptools.

What is the reason for this and how can I make libraries installed in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages?

This computer is used by only me so it doesn't matter but I preferred the former because of the brevity of the path.

Comment: For python 3.10 with same option, it installed in `Program Files/Python310` properlly. I have no concrete guess but maybe remove 3.10.1 and install 3.10, then upgrade to 3.10.1?